# Inkscape export to Core graphics?

Tags: svg, core-graphics, inkscape

is there anyway that i can export inkscape SVG files to iPhone core graphics?
Or maybe a plugin/export tool?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm yet to try and use it in my own project, [SVGKit](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit/) appears as a good looking contender for an SVG parser and Cocoa Core Graphics drawing library.

Comment: I think he's taking about pre-generating the 2-d code from known static svg assets. See my proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only application I know of that can take an  svg (among other things) and spit out core graphics source (among other things) is Opacity on the Mac. The good news is that it does a great job. The bad news is that a) it's not Inkscape, b) it's commercial,  c) updates have stagnated

There is a fully fictional demo and the price of the app is reasonable for what you get. It does do Coccoa or iOS code, plus other rasterizatiins, etc.

Comment: That is correct.  I've been playing around with it and it seems pretty nice.  They've just added support for multiple layers, which makes it pretty useful for handling button states.  It still doesn't have all of the fancy variable support that Opacity has, but it's a nice alternative that does ARC and UIBezierPaths automatically (again, pricey).

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape can write files as png, among other formats but png works fine in Cocoa.

I use rsvg-convert to convert from the command line (unix-like, maybe cygwin, I don't know).

Comment: Gotta love down votes without a comment, particularly since I use this all the time. Also, inkscape can convert at the command line. In some cases it does better than rsvg-convert, other times, it does worse. Depends a little on the SVG.

Comment: My take on the the question is Dan the Man is asking about about exporting SVG to a format that cab be drawn by core graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Illustrator to import svg and then use ai2canvas http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/ plugin to export it into canvas. Then its a lot easier to convert it into core graphicas than from svg.

Comment: Suggesting a different, extremely complex and expensive application, is hardly a solution.